# Intersection of meaning between Lebesgue Measure and Natural Density

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

FYI: the articles linked and their content within are well-known in number theory, so number theory is a tag (correct if need be).

$\textbf{Background}$: This article by [Maier](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-32/issue-2/Primes-in-short-intervals/10.1307/mmj/1029003189.full) states that a given statement is true "for almost all values of $x$" (see page 1 paragraph 2). The article then continues with "By 'for almost all values of $x$' is meant that $x \to \infty$ through any sequence lying outside a certain exceptional set $\mathcal{E}$ of $x$-values, for which the Lebesgue measure of $\mathcal{E} \cap (0, u]$ is $o(u)$ for $u \to \infty$." A different article by [Richards](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272482/1-s2.0-S0022314X00X02181/1-s2.0-0022314X80900311/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEM7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCICIcSSB0ShUn5K002wxsa1g%2BpZwLtrrY9sqO294SoGt3AiAY7b6taQxyPGvN5oxhHVX0ZE6mLrR5pYsUIzrYkUZo2SrbBAin%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMdocAykn9fxKLnCzYKq8ENgyR3qgjryaPGFDo7Z7SmyjuILMny%2BCDaOCnpa0rTUYnleIJyQj7Yeb3vtTamO9jTIMmt%2BL5q3WhvDD0KTRxwiQsgkzFVMXJN016D0R1DDXbg96V%2FTLtVSJKe1uX%2ByqcaoIBMo512T2QyrVAKCpj1zA47kEj4W5ugTYMEyEQE3L8X7Sc5ExJaRLXzA9ZyjP%2FS6%2FuObbvDm7nNHHcJ1ZkRYd7NfEIGKXmgPQhJbzIawQLIvuCzfNZGslvl0fYK6mKRLXxdZ3lKPyXnMv4Y7UTkQN7Hv364IAQXHhwNrxqOETk1Ljix%2FhHPyng9v%2BKjPkpFQwFSxQLvOOh5D79Y%2F%2FKdfzuZjYr6NMbJixhW4cbyZEAV3mCMmL7b6A%2FSVCabR2QcwzXXUvajosFh0Bvp0JYSsK%2FNSGFy1V2SOu%2F06%2Bt7ix5NVRg8Wa1%2FSLOPd5p%2FpN%2BXk3eZnsp8ux2a8e9sAEfCzO6M0EUoHnHATyDEpfueHjixJ570DgNlYVqF8NxwtbfM7MvDAZPAcT0wSC9hu5%2BBgh5Q%2FCujcHf%2BMMQMv11%2FGiSx9BtN727urQKIW7UsfRkgLdtVFJHpuQatwPUGO6fqGFaqngqHZ17LKruB3NPbc%2B%2BpnKEWpE8J2tygGjTyU82P3hJBuD7s5vLuEUtA3OIrplEjdYDZbeSMNXOwsDghl%2BBwlmdydxc0FN1o8xtDkKoSceLyTbcngTOCfkHesDhl%2BzbVGRoNmAQhu32JGjzBTCDr4mUBjqqAfacCeK1bwnWIKkd1TQd251gadccrV1a7cP9gMvVIpr3ED9GEtMVHc%2FXHnalBue%2FijFHVR2Fryic2yBjYrmdzGh2W3zbogYWwSp7bDyDoEFVy%2BXIrgdTqM7AEaDjSb0u%2FNeAyIThGx6frOFmQnS4hRu1x72fKfaQZNdtpDqRAerMvZBOUcP8qHA6HtCaaaIFDnwR6tMIrg3gr7YDRMukzBW19Ml0z7Hg8JRc&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220516T141512Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSRMTNBZZ%2F20220516%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1b64e2659b80b4f975aa29f998e148e502f8107bae72f95d7cdf69102a3837d3&hash=faaaa163b6e681989b314da1ed11c6d71cf247b80d24e8ebed7de5734ae8170f&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022314X80900311&tid=spdf-4c94e200-a3e0-48cf-aa57-4b5ba93c7a46&sid=c97ff201970782481659db67aaf45f9f540dgxrqa&type=client&ua=53540d52025f500c0d&rr=70c4b95bca9b2934) comments on the same statement in a sightly different manner: "[the statement] is true for most values of $x$, that is the set of values of $x$ for which [the statement] holds has asymptotic density one as $x \to \infty$." Richards then follows up by stating that asymptotic density one for a set $S$ of positive real numbers means "measure$(S \cap [0, x])/x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$." I understand both of these renditions of the same claim to be also given using [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density): [the statement] is true for $x \in S$ where $t(x)/x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ and $t(x)$ is the number of elements in $S$ no greater than $x$.

$\textbf{Question}$:

1. Are all three of these renditions equivalent? Is there any difference between them?
2. The Lebesgue measure of a countable set of real numbers is $0$, so how is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathcal{E} \cap (0, u]$ not equal to zero? I understand that $\mathcal{E}$ may indeed be uncountable, but this is not given as a fact.
3. When considering sets of real numbers, how do Lebesgue measure and measure differ, and how do these two concepts related to the natural density of the sets that they are involved in? My understanding is that Lebesgue measure has a vastly different meaning than natural density, so I am confused on how they provide similar meanings in this context.

Any help would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P(x)$ is a property which may hold for $x\in[0,\infty)$. Here are two different properties that $P$ may satisfy, though they are by no means exhaustive. (Throughout, "measure" refers to Lebesgue measure.)

1. $\mathrm{measure}(\{x:P(x)\ \text{fails}\}) = 0$. In this case, we say that $P(x)$ holds for (Lebesgue-)almost every $x$.
2. For some "exceptional" set $\mathcal E\subset[0,\infty)$, we have
   $$
   \lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm{measure}(\mathcal E\cap[0,u))}{u} = 0,
   $$
   and $P(x)$ fails for all $x\in \mathcal E$. In this case we say that $P(x)$ holds for a set with asymptotic density $1$.  The limit condition means that the exceptional set has "asymptotic density zero," but it is certainly possible that $\mathcal E$ can have positive Lebesgue measure, so the set of $x$ where $P(x)$ fails in this case can be larger than the set of exceptional $x$ in the first case. There is nowhere specified that $\mathcal E$ needs to be countable in this case. For example, $\mathcal E$ could be the interval $[0,500)$, which has measure $500$. Check that for this example, the limit above still holds.

Briefly, Lebesgue measure and "measure" often mean the same thing in the context of the real number line, but there are other "measures" besides the Lebesgue measure. Asymptotic density refers to quantities such as the limit appearing in 2., and it has little to do with the Lebesgue measure in spite of "measure" appearing in the definition of the limit. If a property $P(x)$ holds for Lebesgue-almost every $x$, this is much stronger than $P(x)$ holding on a set of asymptotic density $1$.